# Hacknet on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: pi-2, games

I know that Hacknet is a relatively light game to run, but would it be feasible to port it over to run on a Raspberry Pi, probably a 2?

The Raspberry Pi 2 Model B comes with:

- 1 GB of RAM
- A 900MHz quad-core ARM Cortex-A7 CPU
- A VideoCore IV 3Dgraphics core

Specs here.

Right now, Hacknet is taking up ~ 120 MB of RAM on my PC, so by that statistic it would be able to run on the Pi. However, it would have to be ported into another language (Python?) to be on the Pi.

TL;DR - Is it possible to port Hacknet to run on a Raspberry Pi?

**Note:** I have already bought the game.

*Post moved from here at Arqade.*

Comment: The issue is not the porting to another language (in fact you'll be able to compile or interpret most languages on the Pi) but porting to another platform. I do not know this *Hacknet* of yours but is it open source?

Comment: I am not sure whether Hacknet (store.steampowered.com/app/365450) is open source or not. I don't believe it is, as you have to buy it.

Comment: If it's not open source, what are you planning to base your port on? You could, I suppose, rewrite it from first principles, but 120MB is no small amount of code. Pretty sure you'd have to keep it to yourself as well - you'd be violating all manner of copyright and licensing protections if you published any of it.

Comment: It's supposedly available for windows only. The stage is open for the *emulators*.

Answer (score 1):

Simple. It's not open-source, so you can't port it. Although you could try contacting the author of the game and seeing if they can get it to work. If it's able to run on SteamOS and/or Linux then it might be possible to get a build for Raspberry Pi. Buy the game first so you can demonstrate a legitimate interest.

Alternatively, you could write your own game on the same basic premises, but I'd bet that doing it properly will end up being a lot of work. One way to start would be to simply build the game into/onto an existing Linux shell or write your own shell and the game at the same time (http://web2.clarkson.edu/class/cs444/labs/lab01/Writing_Your_Own_Shell.html). You might be able to get a fancier text interface running, using ncurses or similar, to sort of emulate the click and point screen the hacknet screenshots show, but you'd only be able to see it or the shell one at a time.

I'd recommend you try the former as the second will be very hard and provide no graphics of any sort unless you implement some.